# Getting the numeric value after the hyphen in a string

Tags: javascript, string

How can I extract and get just the numeric value after the hyphen in a string?

Here is the input string:

```
var x = "-2147467259"
```

After some processing.... return:

```
alert(2147467259)
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Just `alert(-x)`? Is the minus always the first character in the string?

Comment: if x always consists a hyphen followed by digits, (x*-1) will return the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) away the hyphen:

```
alert(+x.replace("-", ""));
```

And yes, the `+` is important. It converts a string to a number; so you're removing the hypen by replacing it with nothing, and then essentially casting the result of that operation into a number. This operation will also work if no hyphen is present.

You could also use [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to achieve this:

```
alert(+x.substr(1));
```

You could also use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the string to a number (which will end up negative if a hyphen is persent), and then find its absolute value:

```
alert(Math.abs(parseInt(x, 10));
```

As **Bergi** notes, if you can be sure that the first character in the string is always a hyphen, you can simple return its negative, which will by default cast the value into a number and then perform the negative operation on it:

```
alert(-x);
```

You could also check to see if the number is negative or positive via a tertiary operator and then perform the respective operation on it to ensure that it is a positive Number:

```
x = x >= 0 ? +x : -x;
```

This may be cheaper in terms of performance than using `Math.abs`, but the difference will be minuscule either way.

As you can see, there really are a variety of ways to achieve this. I'd recommend reading up on [JavaScript string functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and [number manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) in general, as well as examining [JavaScript's Math object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) to get a feel for what tools are available to you when you go to solve a problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

1. `Math.abs(parseInt("-2147467259"))`

Or

1. `"-2147467259".replace('-','')`

or

1. `"-2147467259".replace(/\-/,'')`

> #1 option is converting the string to numbers. The #2 approach is removing all `-` from the string and the #3 option even though it will not be necessary on this example uses Regular Expression but I wanted to show the possibility of using RegEx in replace situations.

If you need a number as the final value #1 is your choice if you need strings #2 is your choice.

Comment: "after or " is the answer of @Elliot

Comment: @AbdennourToumi I just noticed the other answer but presuming it is a copy sounds unfair

Comment: ah!  ok.. i am so sorry